# What does .comm mean?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

I just translated this program,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int dam[1000][1000];


int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

to assembly using gcc producing,

```
    .cstring
LC0:
    .ascii "Hello, World!\0"
    .text
.globl _main
_main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    pushl   %ebx
    subl    $20, %esp
    call    L3
"L00000000001$pb":
L3:
    popl    %ebx
    leal    LC0-"L00000000001$pb"(%ebx), %eax
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    L_puts$stub
    movl    $0, %eax
    addl    $20, %esp
    popl    %ebx
    leave
    ret
.comm _dam,1000000,5
    .section __IMPORT,__jump_table,symbol_stubs,self_modifying_code+pure_instructions,5
L_puts$stub:
    .indirect_symbol _puts
    hlt ; hlt ; hlt ; hlt ; hlt
    .subsections_via_symbols
```

What does .comm mean? Does dam use heap space, stack space or data space?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the `as` manual:

> ..comm declares a common symbol named
>   symbol. When linking, a common symbol
>   in one object file may be merged with
>   a defined or common symbol of the same
>   name in another object file. If ld
>   does not see a definition for the
>   symbol--just one or more common
>   symbols--then it will allocate length
>   bytes of uninitialized memory. length
>   must be an absolute expression. If ld
>   sees multiple common symbols with the
>   same name, and they do not all have
>   the same size, it will allocate space
>   using the largest size.
>
> When using ELF, the .comm directive
>   takes an optional third argument. This
>   is the desired alignment of the
>   symbol, specified as a byte boundary
>   (for example, an alignment of 16 means
>   that the least significant 4 bits of
>   the address should be zero). The
>   alignment must be an absolute
>   expression, and it must be a power of
>   two. If ld allocates uninitialized
>   memory for the common symbol, it will
>   use the alignment when placing the
>   symbol. If no alignment is specified,
>   as will set the alignment to the
>   largest power of two less than or
>   equal to the size of the symbol, up to
>   a maximum of 16.

Answer (score 7):

> #### .comm  name, size, alignment

The .comm directive allocates storage in the data section. The storage is referenced by the identifier name. Size is measured in bytes and must be a positive integer. Name cannot be predefined. Alignment is optional. If alignment is specified, the address of name is aligned to a multiple of alignment.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E28388/eoiyg.html